# How to rotate three ad networks - iAd and Admob and OAS tag?

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob, iad, oas

The behavior I am creating is that a OAS ad appears and if it fails then  an iAd appears and if it also fails an AdMob ad appears.  It should cycle through the three choices on a rotation.  At the moment, I am   seeing iAd only or direct ad only.  I have not seen any AdMob ads appear.  Do anyone has a way of setting this up so that the three ad networks rotate?

Please Reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe Adwhirl is what you're looking for. https://www.adwhirl.com/